# Excel VBA: How to filter a range based on colour and then output the result into SUM

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function FILTER_COL that's supposed to filter the cells in a range rng which have the same colour as a cell from_cell:

```
Function FILTER_COL(from_cell As String, rng As Range)
Dim colour As Integer
For Each cell In Range(from_cell)
    colour = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
Next cell

Dim Out As Variant
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = colour Then
        Out.Add (cell.Value)
    End If
Next cell
FILTER_COL = Out
End Function
```

I then put the result into SUM as follows:

```
SUM(FILTER_COL("A55",K50:K52))
```

It gives a #VALUE! error if there's any cell in the range K50:K52 which has the same colour as A55.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return an array or a range object. A range object would be better suited, but there is no way afaik to specify an empty range in case no color matches. So I used an array of doubles:

```
Function FILTER_COL(from_cell As String, rng As Range) As Double()
    Dim v() As Double
    ReDim v(rng.Count)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    Dim colour As Integer
    colour = Range(from_cell).Interior.ColorIndex

    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = colour And IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            v(i) = cell.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    FILTER_COL = v
End Function
```